# How do I refer to a data frame element with strings in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
n <- 1
sn <- "n"
get (sn)
```

This will work. However, the following won't work:

```
n <- as.data.frame(matrix(1,2,2))
sn <- "n$V1"
get (sn)
```

How should I make this work?

```
eval(parse(text=sn))
```

works. Thanks.

I am doing that because there are 1000 variables in the dataframe and I need a variable passed from a function to tell which variable out of the 1000 variables that I need to work further on.

Comment: You may need `eval(parse(text=sn))`

Comment: Why are you doing it this way?  It's not a good idea.

Comment: must be a duplicate ...

Comment: there are no doubt better ways to accomplish what you seem to want to and i'm 99.9% positive you'd get help on that if you provided a more complete example of the problem you're actually trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly want to pass just the name of the column within the data frame, then use `[[`-indexing to retrieve the vector you want:

```
n <- as.data.frame(matrix(1,2,2))
sn <- "V1"
n[[sn]]
## [1] 1 1
```