# Evaluate dataframe$column expression stored as a string value

Tags: r, get, eval

Can a string of the form below be evaluated so that it is equivalent to the same "literal" expression?

Example data and code:

```
df.name = data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = LETTERS[seq(1:5)], col3 = letters[seq(1:5)], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
col.name = "col2"
row.num = "4"

var1 = str_c("df.name$", col.name,"[",row.num,"]")

> var1
[1] "df.name$col2[4]"
```

The literal works as expected

```
> df.name$col2[4]
[1] D
```

`get()` is not equivalent:

```
get(var1)
## Error in get(var1) : object 'df.name$col2[4]' not found
```

This form of `get()` "works" but does not solve the problem

```
get("df.name")$col2[4]
[1] D
```

Per other posts I've tried `eval(parse())` and `eval(parse(text()))` without success.

I'm trying to create a function that will search (subset) `df.name` using the `col.name` passed to the function.  I want to avoid writing a separate function for each column name, though that will work since I can code `df.name$col2[row.num]` as a "literal".

## EDIT

The example code should have shown the row.num as type numeric / integer, i.e., `row.num = 4`

Comment: Parsing code as strings is never the answer.  `df.name[[col.name]][as.numeric(row.num)]` is a possibility for you.  But I think you should ask yourself how you ended up with a character representation of a row number and start there.

Comment: Near-duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560780/how-do-i-refer-to-a-data-frame-element-with-strings-in-r/39563674#39563674

Comment: if you really need to do this, `eval(parse(text=var1))` should work (it works for me).  But @RichScriven's solution (but with `get(df.name)` instead of `df.name`) should work.

Comment: @Rich Scriven - the row number comes from a "for loop".  The sample code is just to show the construct. The task at hand is not vectorisable since future rows depend on results of earlier rows. Again, I can avoid the paste/str_c via a separate function for each of the columns from which I need to retrieve a value.  However, if I can pass the column name as a parameter to the function, well then I need only one function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to create a function that will search (subset) df.name using the col.name passed to the function.

Set up data:

```
df.name = data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = LETTERS[1:5], ## seq() is unnecessary
                     col3 = letters[1:5], 
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
col.name = "col2"
row.num = "4"
```

Solving your ultimate (index the data frame by column name) rather than your proximal (figure out how to use `get()`/`eval()` etc.) question: as @RichardScriven points out,

```
f <- function(col.name,row.num,data=df.name)
   return(data[[col.name]][as.numeric(row.num)])
}
```

should work. It would probably be more idiomatic if you specified the row number as numeric rather than character, if possible ...

Comment: I will edit my question to note that the example row number should, more appropriately, have been numeric().

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there:

```
> eval(parse(text = var1))
[1] "D"
```

Because parse expecting file by default, you need to specify the `text` parameter.